# How do I do multiple backtracked words if only with periods or single characters in parentheses in regex?

Tags: regex

I have an entry like so:

```
Beetle as creator. So. Am. Indian (Lengua): Métraux BBAE CXLIII (1) 367 (Guaranyi):
```

which I am trying to parse out to find the names of tribes. I want to be able to get So. Am. Indian, Lengua and Guaranyi, but avoid the (1).

I've gotten this so far:

```
\w+.[A-Za-z0-9_.()]+:| \(.*?\)
```

which gives me Indian, Lengua and Guaranyi but also the 367 which isn't correct. I'm not great at regex and I've just spent three hours on this so I was hoping someone might give me a pointer. thanks!

Comment: How do you plan to do this, and if you already know the names of these tribes, do you need to do use a script?

Comment: Could you please clarify **exactly** what the expected output is, given that input?

Comment: How to make difference between a name of tribe and a common word?

Comment: I don't know the names of the tribes. I'm trying to collect them all and there are 50,000+ records, each with between 1 and 10 tribes (obviously a lot of tribes overlapping)

Comment: what I'd like for the output to be is: "So. Am. Indian", "Lengua", "Guaranyi"

Comment: One way to sort between a Tribe and common word is usually tribes are capitalized and other random things aren't, but I will need to scan later on. What helps is that there is a over-reaching category first: So. Am. Indian and the tribes Lengua and Guaranyi fit in that. If there's no colon / other tribe, before a word in ( ) that also helps to remove cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria to distinguish tribes and common words are not really clear for me, but here is an **attempt in  perl:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use utf8;

my $str = 'Beetle as creator. So. Am. Indian (Lengua): Métraux BBAE CXLIII (1) 367 (Guaranyi): ';
my @tribes = $str =~ /((?:\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+\.?\s?)+)/g;
print Dumper\@tribes;
```

**explanation:**

```
/               : Regex delimiter
  (             : Begin capture group 1
    (?:         : Begin non capture group
      \p{Lu}    : An uppercase letter
      \p{Ll}+   : One or more lowercase letter
      \.?       : A dot 0 or 1 time
      \s?       : A space 0 or 1 time
    )+          : End non capture group repeated 1 or more time
  )             : End of captur group
/               : Regex delimiter
g               : Global search
```

**output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
      'Beetle ',
      'So. Am. Indian ',
      'Lengua',
      'Métraux',
      'Guaranyi'
    ];
```

Like you can see it captures also `Beetle` and `Métraux`.

**Same code in php:**

```
$str = 'Beetle as creator. So. Am. Indian (Lengua): Métraux BBAE CXLIII (1) 367 (Guaranyi): ';
preg_match_all('/((?:\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+\.?\s?)+)/u', $str, $tribes);
print_r($tribes);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Beetle
            [1] => So. Am. Indian
            [2] => Lengua
            [3] => Métraux
            [4] => Guaranyi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Beetle
            [1] => So. Am. Indian
            [2] => Lengua
            [3] => Métraux
            [4] => Guaranyi
        )

)
```

Comment: thank you! this is very helpful and has helped me along very much. :)